# Crystal Report leaves blank rows at the end of the page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm trying to fix my report. I have 4 columns in "Details" and they are all set to "Can Grow".
The problem is that if one of the column is too big (which makes the row big as well), and the space left for the last row on the page is slightly less then needed, it will leave a blank row and make the next row (with information) on the next page.

How do I avoid that last empty row if crystal report can't fit anything in it?

P.S. I'm using Crystal Report on Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... if I understand, you want to make use of the empty space after a large-ish detail row displays.

You can  a) limit the "can grow" to a set number of lines (not recommended), or you can
         b) go into Section Expert and for that row and/or objects in that row, 
            turn off "Keep Together" (row) and/or "Keep Object Together" (field/column)

These are UIs / settings in the CR developer.

There will be corresponding settings through the VS2008 CR interface.

Turning off "Keep Together", "Keep Object Together" will let the objects break across the page boundaries.  It can give some interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

in detail uncheck "keep together".

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds... :(  Concise, tho'!